# Apache MINA FTP server, how to?

Tags: apache, ftp

```
import org.apache.ftpserver.config.*;
import org.apache.ftpserver.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpException;
import org.apache.ftpserver.listener.ListenerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.command.*;
import org.apache.ftpserver.config.spring.*;
import org.apache.*;
import org.apache.ftpserver.impl.*;

public class ftpko {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();

    ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();

    // set the port of the listener
    factory.setPort(2221);

    // replace the default listener
    serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());

    // start the server
    FtpServer server = serverFactory.createServer(); 
            server.start();



}

}
```

I'm trying to run this code, but i'm getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type FtpException
```

here's the stacktrace:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger        (org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpServerContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly
```

What's wrong with this? thanks. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing anything about MINA ftp , but the compilation error suggest that you have forgotten to add a throws to the main method...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FtpException { ... }
```